# Hyperlink that switches to a "hidden" tab in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I want a hyperlink to work in practical terms just as a tab button would. This is my code so far (it has two normal tabs and a "hyperlink tab"):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
      sidebarUserPanel(
        actionLink("show_hidden_tab", "Show Hidden Tab")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
      
    uiOutput("hidden_tab_ui")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hiddenTabContent <- reactiveVal(F)
  
  observeEvent(input$show_hidden_tab, {
    hiddenTabContent(!hiddenTabContent())
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    hiddenTabContent(F)
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", selected = input$tabs)
  })
  
  output$hidden_tab_ui <- renderUI({
    if(hiddenTabContent()){
      h2("Hidden Tab Content")
      
    }else{
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
                h2("Tab 1 Content")
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
                h2("Tab 2 Content")
        )
      )
      
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It almost works properly, except for the fact that when the app is launched, the content of tab 1 is not displayed until the user switches to tab 2, and then goes back to tab 1

How can I fix this and make the first tab's content visible as soon as the app is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an option where you can use `shinyjs::hidden` to hide the menuItem.

Then you can use your `actionLink` as a way to show the hidden tab item by using `updateTabItems`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
      hidden(menuItem("Tab 3", tabName = "hidden_tab", icon = icon("chart-bar"))),
      sidebarUserPanel(
        actionLink("show_hidden_tab", "Show Hidden Tab")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              h2("Tab 1 Content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
              h2("Tab 2 Content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "hidden_tab",
            h2("Hidden Content")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # display hidden tab when action link is clicked
  observeEvent(input$show_hidden_tab, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", "hidden_tab")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`shihydashboard::tabItems()` shows that behavior when the tabs are created dynamically with `shiny::renderUI()`. You can insert some Javascript that waits for the browser to load the tabs and then activate the first tab. I modified your code below to do that.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
      sidebarUserPanel(
        actionLink("show_hidden_tab", "Show Hidden Tab")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$script(
      HTML(
        "
          function waitForElm(selector) {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                  if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                      return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                  }

                  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
                      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                          resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                          observer.disconnect();
                      }
                  });

                  observer.observe(document.body, {
                      childList: true,
                      subtree: true
                  });
              });
          }

          waitForElm('#shiny-tab-tab1').then((elm) => {
            //console.log('Element is ready');
            //console.log(elm.textContent);
            elm.classList.add('active');
          });
       "
      )),
    
    
    uiOutput("hidden_tab_ui")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hiddenTabContent <- reactiveVal(F)
  
  observeEvent(input$show_hidden_tab, {
    hiddenTabContent(!hiddenTabContent())
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    hiddenTabContent(F)
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", selected = input$tabs)
  })
  
  output$hidden_tab_ui <- renderUI({
    if(hiddenTabContent()){
      h2("Hidden Tab Content")
      
    }else{
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
                h2("Tab 1 Content")
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
                h2("Tab 2 Content"))
        
      )
      
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I noticed that there are more issues with this solution than just the first tab not being shown on page load:

- When the hidden tab link is clicked again, nothing is shown.
- After the hidden tab link is clicked, the last clicked menu item is still `active` and can not be clicked before another menu item is clicked.

I think you might be better off not using `renderUI()` to create the tabs. Instead, create three tabs in the UI definition, but skip the menu item for the third (hidden) tab. Attach an `onlick` event to the `actionLink` that execute a Javascript function which:

1. deactivates the currently active tab.
2. activates the hidden tab
3. deactivates the currently active menu item

Here are some Javascript snippets for you to toy with:

When tab 2 is active/displayed, the code below will show tab 1 and hide tab 2.

```
document.querySelector("#shiny-tab-tab1").classList.add('active');
document.querySelector("#shiny-tab-tab2").classList.remove('active');
```

This code will deactivate all sidebar menu items, making them clickable.

```
menu_items = document.querySelector('.sidebar-menu').getElementsByTagName('li');
menu_items_arr = [...menu_items];
menu_items_arr.map(d => d.classList.remove('active'))
```